# Entity Framework 5: How to upgrade a base entity to a inherited entity

Tags: inheritance, entity-framework-5

**Business Scenario**:
We are building a student management system. Initially, we manage Applicant records with some basic information. Later on, when an applicant is selected as a student, we capture additional data (student registration number, etc..) in the Student record.

**Data Model**:
I am using Entity Framework 5. In my model, I have a base entity called Applicant and another entity called Student which is inherited from Applicant (Student:Applicant).

**Requirement**: I want to "upgrade" an Applicant record to a Student record. How to acheive this using the EF.

**Update**
When checked the database, I found two tables; Applicants and Applicants_Student, where the later's primary key is a foreign key of Applicant. If we are to access the DB directly, then the preferred solution would be to Insert a record to the Applicants_Student table with related primary key of the Applicant record. Wonder how to do this using EF.

Comment: Create a new Student record using the data from the Applicant record, and then delete the Applicant record (or give it a state like *Accepted*).

Comment: Thanks Stijin, but this has a small issue. I checked the database and found two tables in this (Applicants, Applicants_Student). The Applicants_Student table store the extra information and Sharing the primary key (also a foreign key)with Applicant table. So if I keep the existing record and add a new Student with copied data, that will add another record to the Applicant table :(

Comment: Oh BTW, deleting the existing record is tricky as there can be additional related entities. If we are to access the DB directly, then the preferred solution would be to Insert a record to the Applicants_Student table with related primary key of the Applicant record. Wonder how to do this using EF.

Comment: Can you share your class definitions for `Applicant` and `Student`, and the relevant lines from your `DbContext` class?